# How to add instance variable to Scrapy CrawlSpider?

Tags: python, scrapy

I am running a CrawlSpider and I want to implement some logic to stop following some of the links in mid-run, by passing a function to `process_request`.

This function uses the spider's **class** variables in order to keep track of the current state, and depending on it (and on the referrer URL), links get dropped or continue to be processed:

```
class BroadCrawlSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'bitsy'
    start_urls = ['http://scrapy.org']
    foo = 5

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(), callback='parse_item', process_request='filter_requests', follow=True),
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        <some code>

    def filter_requests(self, request):
        if self.foo == 6 and request.headers.get('Referer', None) == someval:
             raise IgnoreRequest("Ignored request: bla %s" % request)
        return request
```

I think that if I were to run several spiders on the same machine, they would all use the same **class** variables which is not my intention.

Is there a way to add **instance** variables to CrawlSpiders? Is only a single instance of the spider created when I run Scrapy?

I could probably work around it with a dictionary with values per process ID, but that will be ugly...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [spider arguments](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#spider-arguments) would be the solution in your case.

When invoking scrapy like `scrapy crawl some_spider`, you could add arguments like `scrapy crawl some_spider -a foo=bar`, and the spider would receive the values via its constructor, e.g.:

```
class SomeSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    def __init__(self, foo=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SomeSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # Do something with foo
```

What's more, as [`scrapy.Spider` actually sets all additional arguments as instance attributes](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/spiders/__init__.py#L30), you don't even need to explicitly override the `__init__` method but just access the `.foo` attribute. :)

Comment: Thanks @starrify! I think I prefer using `__init__` for readability, otherwise it will be impossible to understand where these variables are coming from. However, once I do that, I can skip passing the spider any arguments and simply set use your example to set up the instance variables inside `__init__`, which is what I am going to do. Thanks again!

Comment: @UriCS  by skipping passing the spider any arguments—do you mean passing `cb_kwargs` to each callback of the spider? Because whether you set the instance variables explicitly or not, their values will be instantiated with spider arguments...