# Creating Scrapy instance variables

Tags: python, scrapy, instance

I would like to pass arguments to my spider in order to search a site based on the input, but I am struggling to set instance variables.  It seems that **init** is getting called twice, the first time it uses the arguments I pass, and the second time it seems to be getting called by a scrapy function that doesn't pass along my input and resets self.a and self.b to the default value: 'f'.

I read on another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39188109) that scrapy would automatically set any passed variables as instance attributes, but I have not found a way to access them.

Is there a solution to this, or an easier way that I am missing?

```
import scrapy
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest 
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings


class PracticeSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'practice'

    def __init__(self, a='f', b='f' *args, **kwargs):
        super(PracticeSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        print self.a
        print self.b

    def start_requests(self):
        print self.a
        print self.b
        yield SplashRequest(''.join(["https://www.google.com/search?q=",
                             self.a, "+", self.b]), self.practice_parse, args={'wait': 0.5})

    def practice_parse(self):
        pass


# list of crawlers
TO_CRAWL = [PracticeSpider]

# crawlers that are running
RUNNING_CRAWLERS = []

for spider in TO_CRAWL:

    process = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())
    for spider in TO_CRAWL:
        process.crawl(spider(a='first', b='second'))
    process.start()
```

Comment: [`CrawlerProcess.crawl()` signature](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/api.html#scrapy.crawler.CrawlerProcess.crawl) is `(spiderclass, *args, **kwargs)`, one does not pass a Spider instance. So the way to pass arguments to the spider in your case is `process.crawl(spider, a='first', b='second')`

Comment: @paultrmbrth Ah I see, that fixed the problem.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look into the **[meta](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html)** argument, which is a dictionary:

```
def some_function(self, response):
    ...
    yield Request(url=page, 
        callback=self.parse_page, 
        meta = {'var1' : "value1", 'var1' : "value2})
```

then, inside the parse_page function you can retrieve your variables as follows:

```
def parse_page(self, response):
    ...
    var1 = response.meta["var1"]
    var2 = response.meta["var2"]
```